# What file to add to nginx certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I got a RaspberryPi on which I want to host Owncloud. So I followed [this tutorial](http://www.techjawab.com/2014/08/how-to-setup-owncloud-7-on-raspberry-pi.html) and it works well except the SSL part. I don't want to use self signed.
I set my own subdomain and it works without ssl, also outside my home network. I didn't try the self signed certificate.

The command which I used created the certificates (found in this [tutorial](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-nginx.htm)):

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out /etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.csr -keyout /etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.key -subj "/C=NL/ST=none/L=none/O=none/OU=none/CN=my.example.com"
```

files

- */etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.csr*
- */etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.key*

In the nginx: */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*

```
## other stuff from tut
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # enforce http
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.csr;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/my_example_com.key;
## other stuff from tut
```

After I submitted the *.csr* content I to my webhoster I recieved a zip with 3 files:

- *my_example_com.cert*
- *CA_Root.cert*
- *CA_Intermediate.cert*

I tried all 3 files for the `ssl_certificate` value they don't work.
So I googled and found multiple sources saying the I needed the merge those files in some order. ([source](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm), [source](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx), [source](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm))

But the file names in my situation are all a bit different and it's just confusing.
Some sources talk about `.crt` files some about `.pem` but I got `.cert`. Does the file extension even matter?

**Does anybody know how I should set(/merge?) these files to make my site work on ssl?**
*note: This is the first time I work with nginx or ssl-certificates*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main fault was the modem from the ISP. After that I figured out it was:

```
sudo cat my_example_com.cert CA_Intermediate.cert CA_Root.cert >> bundle.cert
```

Mainly suggested [here](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Configuring HTTPS servers - SSL certificate chains](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains)

```
    $ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt

The resulting file should be used in the ssl_certificate directive:

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Typo in the chaining: bundle.crt should read CA_Intermediate.crt

Comment: I get the impression you didn't read my entire question. I don't have a `bundle.crt` file.