# http to https redirect in NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, nginx

I have a website in http protocol, now i want to change it to https, but I don't know how to change my default file. This is my default content:

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {


                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

}
```

Do you know what I should add to my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What file to add to nginx certificate](https://superuser.com/questions/849383/what-file-to-add-to-nginx-certificate)

Comment: Please do some research before asking. This is documented in Nginx documentation itself (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) and many tutorials. Please show what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original question and the default configuration file for Nginx:

```
 # HTTPS server

 server {
     listen       443 ssl;
     # server_name  localhost;

     #   Lacking a path, defaults to searching the .conf folder
     ssl_certificate      your.ssl.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key  your.ssl.key;

     ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
     ssl_session_timeout  5m;

     ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

     }
 }
```